# using "be" in the past tense

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I guess the usage of "be" in the passage below is grammatically correct even though the whole narration is in the past tense. Can you, please, explain to me why it is correct and why it is not "was" instead?

> I liked working at the lab and doing all those experiments with acids
>   and alkalines. At first, my interest was so great that I simply
>   ignored Jack's suggestion to use that device. However, the more I
>   continued, the more I was upset about spilling acid on the floor
>   almost every time I experimented on it. One day - almost by accident -
>   I showed up in the nearby lab where the parallel class students were
>   experimenting. What struck me a lot was the fact that they never
>   spilled any liquids that they were "playing with" - not only acids.
>   Another thing that also struck me a lot was that they all were using
>   exactly that device that Jack had suggested that I would do a few days
>   earlier. I quickly went back to my lab and started studying that
>   device. It took me a while to figure out how to use it.  Finally, I
>   realized that that was quite a handy device that I could always use in my
>   experiments **and never be afraid** of spilling acid on the floor again.

Answer (score -1):

I do see one problem with the last sentence in that passage, but I do not think it is "be". I would write:

> Finally, I realized that that was quite a handy device that I could always use in my experiments ***to* never be afraid** of spilling acid on the floor again.

The sentence as written was not grammatical, even beyond your comment on tense. "Be" is correct as part of the infinitive form "to be". Without using the infinitive, the sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What about the word **could** in that sentence? Does it not only tag with **use** ("I could always use") but also with **be** ("I could never be afraid"), therefore, making the sentence grammatical?

Comment: The original sentence is perfectly grammatical. Tashus's rewriting is also grammatical, but has a different meaning. In the original, _always use_ and _never be_ are parallel coordinated terms governed by _could_. In the rewriting, _to be_ becomes a purpose clause. In practice, there's not much difference, but potentially they are very different in meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine The second phrase in the parallel construction doesn't make sense to me when parsed alone. "that was quite a handy device that I could never be afraid of spilling acid on the floor again"  It would work with "such a handy device", but isn't there a problem in the original?

Comment: Yes, you're right, @Tashus, now I've reread it: there's an anacoluthon. But nevertheless, the sentence as given reads perfectly normally to me.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for teaching me a new word!